# How to compare if an id is more than a value in jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use the more than operator in a jquery criteria
For e.g say i want to get all rows where the rowindex is more than a certain value.
Is it possible somehow or do i need create my own function once I have the result set from jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example mentioned in your question, you can just use the [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
// Get all rows with a rowIndex greater than 5:
var rowsPlus5 = $('#mytable tr:gt(5)');
```

For other scenarios, you might need to use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method with a callback function.

Comment: This looks good, any ideas how I can chain multuiple critieria in jquery.
For e.g i'm alreay using a td find:
 table.find("td[ColumnName=" + searchColumn + "]:contains('" + searchVal + "')")
if i want to add a tr gt() critieria too then is it possible to chain them somehow?

Comment: @Rubans: it's probably bordering on obscene and I try and avoid such complex selectors because they don't always work, e.g. `table.find("tr:gt(5) > td[ColumnName=" + searchColumn + "]:contains('" + searchVal + "')")`.  You could also use the `.has()` method or `:has()` selector if you just wanted a reference to the matching TRs and not the TD elements.

Comment: How do I use has()?
The following doesn't seem to return anything:
table.find("td[ColumnName=" + searchColumn + "]:icontains('" + searchVal + "')").has("tr:gt(2)");

Comment: I guess it's because the intial returned return set are all td cells and now I want to get back use the parent element (tr) row index, anyway around this?

Comment: @Rubans: not sure, you might be able to use  the `.parent("tr:gt(5)")` method.  It's not quite the same thing, but you could perform your `.has()` first, `table.find("tr:gt(5)").has("`td[ColumnName=" + searchColumn + "]:contains('" + searchVal + "')");`

Comment: Thanks that works, also liked the each(function) example too but this was nice to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $filtered = $('table').find('tr').filter(function(){
     return (this.rowIndex > 5);
});
```

Works.

It does not work with `$('table').children('tr')`, I have no clue why not. Somebody please?

Comment: $('table').children('tr') finds nothing because tr are children of tbody: table > tbody > tr

Comment: See the docs for [`table.tBodies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.tBodies), a `<tbody>` element is automatically inserted into the DOM if it's not specified.  The `<tr>` elements will be children of that `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something similar to the following:

```
$('tr.selector').each(function(){
    var rowId = $(this).index();
    if (rowId > 5){
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want:

[.slice( start, [ end ] );](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) *Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.*

> **start** An integer indicating the 0-based
>   position after which the elements are
>   selected. If negative, it indicates an
>   offset from the end of the set. 
>   
> **end** An
>   integer indicating the 0-based
>   position before which the elements
>   stop being selected. If negative, it
>   indicates an offset from the end of
>   the set. [If omitted, the range continues until the end of the set](http://#).